# How to solve Call to undefined method App\model\post\::links() error

Tags: laravel, pagination

I am using laravel paginator and I have this code in my blade
`if (post -> count()) For each (post as post) {!!$post->title!!} {!!$post->description!!} @endforeach {{$post->links()}}`

Am getting  Call to undefined method App\model\post::links() error
When I inspect in the console the issue am getting is Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appversion, and navigator.platform.
How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Where is the error in it @foreach(post as post)?

Comment: both of your array and value is the same variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an error in your foreach. You wrote `For each (post as post)` but you probably need something more like `foreach($posts as $post)`. Then, to display the pagination links, use `{{ $posts->links() }}` (note that the `links()` method is called on the collection variable, not the individual model).

Check out https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

Comment: thankyou, it solved the issue, i was using {{$post -> links()} rather than {{posts -> links()}} thankyou.

Comment: No problem. Then please mark my answer as the solution. And for next time you get an error, try to read well and understand the error message. In that case it said the Post model doesn't have a links() method which make sense.